# c: printf("%-16llu", my_var);

Tags: c, types, printf

It's been awhile since I've played with c, and now I find something I've never seen before:

```
printf("%-16llu", my_var);
```

It would seem to be saying print 16 characters of a long unsigned int.  But, what's the second 'l' for?  long long?

Comment: I've searched K&R ANSI C for a clue, but... so far no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%llu
```

Is for `unsigned long long`. This was added in C99 (and much, much after K&R wrote the book).